# Piecewise regression with R: plotting the segments

Tags: r, plot, piecewise

I have 54 points. They represent offer and demand for products. I would like to show there is a break point in the offer.

First, I sort the x-axis (offer) and remove the values that appears twice. I have 47 values, but I remove the first and last ones (doesn't make sense to consider them as break points). Break is of length 45:

```
Break<-(sort(unique(offer))[2:46])
```

Then, for each of these potential break points, I estimate a model and I keep in "d" the residual standard error (sixth element in model summary object).

```
d<-numeric(45)
for (i in 1:45) {
model<-lm(demand~(offer<Break[i])*offer + (offer>=Break[i])*offer)
d[i]<-summary(model)[[6]] }
```

Plotting d, I notice that my smaller residual standard error is 34, that corresponds to "Break[34]": 22.4. So I write my model with my final break point:

```
model<-lm(demand~(offer<22.4)*offer + (offer>=22.4)*offer)
```

Finally, I'm happy with my new model. It's significantly better than the simple linear one. And I want to draw it:

```
plot(demand~offer)
i <- order(offer)
lines(offer[i], predict(model,list(offer))[i])
```

But I have a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In predict.lm(model, list(offer)) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
```

And more important, the lines are really strange on my plot.

[image: My plot with the supposedly two segments, but not joining]

Here are my data:

```
demand <- c(1155, 362, 357, 111, 703, 494, 410, 63, 616, 468, 973, 235,
            180, 69, 305, 106, 155, 422, 44, 1008, 225, 321, 1001, 531, 143,
            251, 216, 57, 146, 226, 169, 32, 75, 102, 4, 68, 102, 462, 295,
            196, 50, 739, 287, 226, 706, 127, 85, 234, 153, 4, 373, 54, 81,
            18)
offer <- c(39.3, 23.5, 22.4, 6.1, 35.9, 35.5, 23.2, 9.1, 27.5, 28.6, 41.3,
           16.9, 18.2, 9, 28.6, 12.7, 11.8, 27.9, 21.6, 45.9, 11.4, 16.6,
           40.7, 22.4, 17.4, 14.3, 14.6, 6.6, 10.6, 14.3, 3.4, 5.1, 4.1,
           4.1, 1.7, 7.5, 7.8, 22.6, 8.6, 7.7, 7.8, 34.7, 15.6, 18.5, 35,
           16.5, 11.3, 7.7, 14.8, 2, 12.4, 9.2, 11.8, 3.9)
```

Comment: 54 points does not seem a very large amount of points to detect such a transistion. You could opt to also post this in stats.stackexchange.com with the specfic question if this is enough points to detect the break in the data. Just my 2 ct.

Comment: I think this is pretty statistically dubious. Better to estimate the breakpoint in the model itself (although that makes it non linear). You can't trust the p-vals or standard errors from the current informal estimation process.

Comment: 54 points isn't a large amount, I agree, but both my linear and my piecewise linear regressions are significant. And moreover, the residual standard error of the piecewise linear model is 103.9 compared to 121.3 for the linear model with two less degrees of freedom. The piecewise model is significantly better.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is an easier approach using `ggplot2`.

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(offer, demand, group = offer > 22.4, geom = c('point', 'smooth'), 
   method = 'lm', se = F, data = dat)
```

EDIT. I would also recommend taking a look at this package `segmented` which supports automatic detection and estimation of segmented regression models.

[image]

UPDATE:

Here is an example that makes use of the R package [segmented](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/index.html) to automatically detect the breaks

```
library(segmented)
set.seed(12)
xx <- 1:100
zz <- runif(100)
yy <- 2 + 1.5*pmax(xx - 35, 0) - 1.5*pmax(xx - 70, 0) + 15*pmax(zz - .5, 0) + 
  rnorm(100,0,2)
dati <- data.frame(x = xx, y = yy, z = zz)
out.lm <- lm(y ~ x, data = dati)
o <- segmented(out.lm, seg.Z = ~x, psi = list(x = c(30,60)),
  control = seg.control(display = FALSE)
)
dat2 = data.frame(x = xx, y = broken.line(o)$fit)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dati, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = dat2, color = 'blue')
```

[image: segmented]

Comment: Thank you for the idea about using the "segmented" package. "Muggeo, V.M.R. (2003) Estimating regression models with unknown break-points. Statistics inMedicine 22, 3055–3071" is an interesting paper to understand what's going on in the package.

Comment: In particular, it has an advantage to the code I used: the two segments are connected! In "The R Book", the author is not mentioning his segments are not connected and is even showing a plot with connected segments...

Comment: Where is an example of using ggplot() with segmented()? I cannot seem to find one anywhere.

Comment: I have added an example that uses `ggplot` with `segmented`.

Comment: After `qplot(…)` I get `Error: Unknown parameters: method, se`

Comment: Is you solution applicable [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949427/plotting-predictions-from-a-piece-wise-mixed-regression-model#64949427) as well?

Answer (score 9):

Vincent has you on the right track. The only thing "weird" about the lines in your resulting plot is that `lines` draws a line between *each* successive point, which means that "jump" you see if it simply connecting the two ends of each line.

If you don't want that connector, you have to split the `lines` call into two separate pieces.

Also, I feel like you can simplify your regression a bit. Here's what I did:

```
#After reading your data into dat
Break <- 22.4
dat$grp <- dat$offer < Break

#Note the addition of the grp variable makes this a bit easier to read
m <- lm(demand~offer*grp,data = dat)
dat$pred <- predict(m)

plot(dat$offer,dat$demand)
dat <- dat[order(dat$offer),]
with(subset(dat,offer < Break),lines(offer,pred))
with(subset(dat,offer >= Break),lines(offer,pred))
```

which produces this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The weird lines are simply due to the order in which the points are plotted.
The following should look better:

```
i <- order(offer)
lines(offer[i], predict(model,list(offer))[i])
```

The warning comes from the fact that the `*` character is interpreted by `lm`.

```
> lm(demand~(offer<22.4)*offer + (offer>=22.4)*offer)
Call:
lm(formula = demand ~ (offer < 22.4) * offer + (offer >= 22.4) * offer)
Coefficients:
            (Intercept)         offer < 22.4TRUE                    offer  
                -309.46                   356.08                    29.86  
      offer >= 22.4TRUE   offer < 22.4TRUE:offer  offer:offer >= 22.4TRUE  
                     NA                   -20.79                       NA
```

In addition, `(offer<22.4)*offer` is a discontinuous function: this is where the discontinuity comes from.

The following should be closer to what you want.

```
model <- lm(
  demand ~ ifelse(offer<22.4,offer-22.4,0) 
           + ifelse(offer>=22.4,offer-22.4,0) )
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I still have the warning message: "Warning message:
In predict.lm(model2, list(offer)) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading". The result is a bit better: I've only one piecewise segment, but I don't understand why there are 3 segments (i.e., my two segments are not connected naturally...)

Comment: Can you please explain why this makes it smooth. Intuitively thought it would be 22.4-offer in first part of function. And offer-22.4 in second part. Doesn't first part mean "if offer is less than 22.4 then calculated offer-22.4", meaning it will give a negative covariate? Therefore our coefficient will be multiplied against these negative values when we estimate the input?