# Segmented linear regression with discontinuous data

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a dataset that looks to be piecewise linear. I would like to perform a segmented linear regression in R. The issue is that there is a discontinuity at the breakpoint. By using some pieces of code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758646/piecewise-regression-with-r-plotting-the-segments) I managed to get something, but I am not satisfied.

## Dataset

Here is a dummy dataset.

[image: equation of the dataset]

```
NB = 100
A1 = 2 # coeff for first part
A2 = 1 # coeff for second part
B1 = 0 # intercept for first part
B2 = 300 # intercept for second part
df = data.frame(n=1:NB)
df$n = sample(500, size=NB, replace=TRUE)
df$noise = sample(20, size=NB, replace=TRUE)-10
my_func <- function(n, noise) {
    if(n < 100) {
        return(A1*n+B1 + noise)
    }
    else {
        return(A2*n+B2 + noise)
    }
}
df$fn = mapply(my_func, df$n, df$noise)
```

## Using `segmented` package

This is quite straightforward, we simply perform a classical linear regression and give it to `segmented`.

```
library(segmented)
library(ggplot2)
model_segmented = segmented(lm(fn~n, data=df), seg.Z = ~ n)
predict_segmented = data.frame(n = df$n, fn = broken.line(model_segmented)$fit)
ggplot(df, aes(x = n, y = fn)) +
    geom_point() + geom_line(data = predict_segmented, color = 'blue')
```

Gives:

[image: plot of the raw data and its linear regression using segmented]

Obviously, `segmented` expects the data to be continuous. It is not the case here, so the regression is not correct.

## “Manual” method

This method is more tedious. First, we compute the break-point by trying all the possible break points and keeping the one which yields the lowest residual. Then, we add a new factor in the linear regression, which tells if the predictor variable is greater or lower than this breakpoint.

```
# Computation of the break-point
Break<-sort(unique(df$n))
Break<-Break[2:(length(Break)-1)]
d<-numeric(length(Break))
for (i in 1:length(Break)) {
    model_manual<-lm(fn~(n<Break[i])*n + (n>=Break[i])*n, data=df)
    d[i]<-summary(model_manual)[[6]]
}
breakpoint = Break[which.min(d)]

# Linear regression using this break-point
df$group = df$n >= breakpoint
model_manual<-lm(fn~n*group, data=df)
dat_pred = data.frame(n = df$n, fn = predict(model_manual, df))
ggplot(df, aes(x = n, y = fn)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(data=dat_pred[dat_pred$n < breakpoint,], color = 'blue') +
    geom_line(data=dat_pred[dat_pred$n >= breakpoint,], color = 'blue')
```

Gives:

[image]

Here, the regression is great.

## Question

Is there a better way to achieve this goal? Can the `segmented` package take discontinuous data, or is there a package that can do this?

My concern is that the second method is a bit long and not very readable.

Answer (score 3):

After spending a tremendous amount of time digging, I believe the chngpt package is the way to go. It can do both continuous and discontinuous segmented regressions. Link here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chngpt/vignettes/chngpt-vignette.pdf

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the chngpt package. I think this answer should be accepted. chngpt can do this using the "stegmented" model. Note the "t". This is not a typo. The model you want is called "stegmented" as opposed to "segmented". I emphasize it because it took me a bit of time to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

*strucchange* will detect the breakpoint using statistically valid methods.  Then, you can fit each piece with whatever model you want. For example, with a seasonal time series you can apply separate ARIMA models to each segment.